# A logic problem about set theory

Tags: combinatorics

In a group of n people, subgroups with common interest are formed (football,tennis,snooker). The number of subgroups equals $2^{n-1}$. Any 3 subgroups have a common member. Prove that there is a person who is a member of all the subgroups.

proof by contradiction seems like a good fit here, but I can't seem to get the details right.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. I see that there are $n$ people, (say $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$) but I'm not sure how many subsets there are. I understand that there are $2^{n-1}$ proper non-empty subsets of $X$ but it seems you only consider some, say $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_k\subset X$. Do you know what $k$ is in this case? It seems that given any distinct $a,b,c$ that you know $Y_a\cap Y_b\cap Y_c\ne\varnothing$ and want to prove that $Y_1\cap\cdots\cap Y_n\ne\varnothing$ but I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you try to clarify please?

Comment: @DanRobertson: I believe that there are $2^n - 2$ proper non-empty subsets. Thus only about half of all possible subsets end up forming.

Comment: @Fargle Yes, I see that now. I think I understand the question.

Comment: @DanRobertson any idea how to prove this?

Comment: @prometheus21 Not really, Perhaps it would be possible to determine the largest collection of subsets where any three intersect but the total intersection is null and show that the size of this is $2^{n-1}-1$. It is certainly at least $2^{n-1}-1$, take subsets $X_i=\{1,\dots,n\}\backslash\{i\}$.

Comment: This looks a bit like a finite version of the delta system lemma. But I'm not sure if one could take some inspiration from there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the subgroups need to be distinct, otherwise there are obvious counterexamples

Comment: Is that American football?

Comment: Haha no, European football.

Comment: The statement is untrue for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the set by $S,$ and let $X$ be the collection of subsets of $S$ as given in the problem. First note that $A\in X$ iff $A^{C}\notin X$ since we have exactly $1/2$ of the total number of subsets. From this we deduce that if $A, B\in X,$ then $A\cap B \in X,$ since $(A\cap B)^{C} \cap A\cap B = \emptyset.$ Now, if $\{x\} \in X$ for some singleton, then we're immediately done, so suppose this isn't true. Then every set of the form $S-\{x\}$ is in $X.$ Taking the intersection of two of these gives a set of the form $S-\{x, y\},$ and we clearly get all such sets. Continuing in this manner gives that every set is in $X,$ a contradiction, so we're done.

Alternatively you can just do this by induction on the intersection of $k$ sets, with the base case being $k=2$ proven above.

Answer (score -2):

Given a finite set $N$ of size $n$, let $O_n$ be a family of subsets of $N$ such that any three elements of $O_n$ have non-empty intersection. Given that $|O_n| = 2^{n-1}$ you want to show that $\exists x \in N \forall o \in O_n : x \in o$.

When forming an $O_n$, the maximum number of subsets of $N$ that can be chosen of a specific size $k$ is exactly the number of choices from $N$ where one element is fixed; this is exactly $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. Fixing one choice ensures that all the subsets of size $k$ obey the requirement at any three subsets share an element.

Notice that enumerating the maximum choices for each $k \le n$ forms a row in Pascal's Triangle, and the sum of all the maximum counts for each $k$ is equal to $2^{n-1}$. Therefore, in order to form an $O_n$ whose cardinality is exactly $2^{n-1}$, the maximum number of each size $k$ subset must be chosen. This includes one singleton subset (if no singletons are chosen, then one more set must be chosen to reach the appropriate size, but one more choice from any other size subset would violate the maximum for that size). Thus, in order for $O_n$ to satisfy the requirement that any three subsets share an element, the fixed choice in each size $k$ subset must be the element of $N$ in the singleton.

Therefore the singleton choice is the $x$ that satisfies $\exists x \in N \forall o \in O_n : x \in o$

Comment: Any comments about why the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand your argument either. It looks like you are counting the maximum number $m$ of sets that can have one common element. This is certainly necessary that $2^{n-1} \leq m$ for the proposition to be provable, but I don't see how $m = 2^{n-1}$ actually proves it. Also, you didn't use the other hypothesis, which looks a bit suspicious...

Comment: @A.P. I do use the other hypothesis. Since any three subsets must share one element, and the singleton set must be chosen, then any three subsets must include the singleton, which means that the one common element must be the singleton in every case.

Comment: Still, you didn't address the other issue. It looks like you measure the maximum size $m$ of a collection of subsets which satisfies the thesis (i.e. which have a common element). I understand how you could use it to *disprove* the proposition, but not how $m = 2^{n-1}$ gives you a proof that a singleton must be chosen.

Comment: @A.P. Perhaps I was too verbose. I've condensed the argument and made the use of the hypotheses  more obvious.

Comment: What you need to explain is "the maximum number of subsets of $N$ that can be chosen of a specific size $k$ is exactly the number of choices from N where one element is fixed", which isn't obvious at all. The rest can then be condensed in a couple of lines: since the fixed element for each size is arbitrary, you can just count all the sets that contain a single element, which is the same as measuring the cardinality of the power set of a set of size $n-1$. To see this, just substitute the singleton with the empty set.